# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'recipebook'

Tags: python, database

im attempting to create an environment variable for my db URI. when i hardcode the URI without using ev it works fine. when i attempt to use ev im unsuccessful.

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

#connect to mongodb
app = Flask(__name__)
client = os.environ.get('MONGO_URI')
db = client.recipebook


@app.route('/')
#returning the index.html template
def index():
    recipes = [recipe for recipe in db.recipes.find({})]
    return render_template('index.html', recipes=recipes)

#setting up flask
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=os.getenv('IP'), port=os.getenv('PORT'), debug=True)
```

the outcome im expecting is for my connection string to work successfully. when i do have the full URI in my code it does work. but when i use an environment variable i get the error message of :

"line 9, in 
    db: MongoClientobject = client.recipebook
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'recipebook'"

when i delete line 9 all together i get a successful connection but with an error message of "NameError: name 'db' is not defined"

Comment: What is the line of code that works? `client = ....`?

Comment: client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv:      URI goes here

Comment: You're now setting the URI of your MongoDB server/cluster as the `client` variable (so it's a string, which does not have the property `recipebook`). You should do `client = MongoClient(os.environ.get('MONGO_URI'))`.

Comment: thank you stephan, appreciate it